# Out of range value for column 'date' when executing my python script

Tags: python, mysql, csv, dictionary

I have created a python script that reads a csv file and then stores the data into variables using a dictionary.
then I insert the variables to mysql database.
Everytime is working 100% .. except when I try to insert a date.

i get the error:

> Out of range value for column 'date'

I printed the variable date which is: 2015-02-28 
it is exactly what I need! but I still get the error message..
Also, it inserts the value 0000-00-00 instead of 2015-02-28 to my table :s 
I think the problems is that 2015-02-28 might be a string.. how can i convert it to date?

This is my python script:

```
#4 python script to insert all data to mysql

#!/usr/bin/python
from StringIO import StringIO
import numpy as np
import csv
import MySQLdb
import os
from datetime import datetime,date,timedelta

dict= {}
infile= open('csv_err1.log','r')
lines= infile.readlines()
for i in lines:
    eventKey, count, totalDuration, average   = [a.strip() for a in i.split(',')]
    dict.setdefault(eventKey, []).append((int(count), int(totalDuration), float(average)))

date = date.today() - timedelta(1)

app_launch_time =dict["app_launch_time"][0][0]
bup_login_error =dict["bup_login_error"][0][0]
crash =dict["crash"][0][0]
parental_controls_error =dict["parental_controls_error"][0][0]
playback_error =dict["playback_error"][0][0]
qp_library_failed_reauthentication =dict["qp_library_failed_reauthentication"][0][0]
qp_library_failed_to_start =dict["qp_library_failed_to_start"][0][0]
search_error =dict["search_error"][0][0]
video_load_time =dict["video_load_time"][0][0]
tbr_error =dict["tbr_error"][0][0]
live_channels_metadata_request_failed =dict["live_channels_metadata_request_failed"][0][0]
vod_catalog_metadata_request_failed =dict["vod_catalog_metadata_request_failed"][0][0]

app_launch_time_avg =dict["app_launch_time"][0][2]
video_load_time_avg =dict["video_load_time"][0][2]

print date

# Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="bravoecholimalima",db="capacityreports_mobiletv")

cursor = db.cursor()

# Prepare SQL query to INSERT a record into the database.
sql = ("""INSERT INTO errorscounted (date,app_launch_time,bup_login_error,crash, parental_controls_error,playback_error,qp_library_failed_reauthentication,qp_library_failed_to_start,search_error,video_load_time,tbr_error,live_channels_metadata_request_failed,vod_catalog_metadata_request_failed,app_launch_time_avg,video_load_time_avg) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""" %(date,app_launch_time, bup_login_error, crash, parental_controls_error,playback_error,qp_library_failed_reauthentication,qp_library_failed_to_start,search_error,video_load_time,tbr_error,live_channels_metadata_request_failed,vod_catalog_metadata_request_failed,app_launch_time_avg,video_load_time_avg))


try:
   # Execute the SQL command
   cursor.execute(sql)
   # Commit your changes in the database
   db.commit()
   for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print row[0]

except:
   # Rollback in case there is any error
   db.rollback()

# disconnect from server
cursor.close()
db.close()
```

any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated :)

edit:
this is my csv_err1.log file:

```
app_launch_time,12247,118616277,9685.33
video_load_time,12966,123702815,9540.55
eventKey,2,0,0
playback_error,3773,0,0
qp_library_failed_reauthentication,230,0,0
search_error,183,0,0
epg_metadata_request_failed,5,0,0
live_channels_metadata_request_failed,13,0,0
vod_catalog_metadata_request_failed,1,0,0
bup_login_error,20,0,0
qp_library_failed_to_start,295,0,0
0,9,0,0
tbr_error,389,0,0
crash,218,0,0
parental_controls_error,123,0,0
```

Comment: A couple of tips unrelated to your main question. (a) `dict` is not a recommended variable name in Python, because it shadows the `dict` class. (b) If you want to process a file line by line, see this answer for a better technique: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11130804/55857.

Comment: Thank you FMc
I will change the dict to mydict.
But the read line that i created works 110% ..
If you have suggestions for the date It would be appreciated :)

Comment: Can you provide output of SHOW CREATE TABLE errorscounted. And example of your csv file?

Comment: I have added the csv file.
Stackoverflow doesnt allow me to add a picture of myphpmyadmin table since i dont have the reputation yet :P
but that said, i can instert all the values into the table except date which inserts 0000-00-00

Comment: anyone ? :(
losing hope here

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution to my problem! :)
I couldn't insert a variable date in python into mysql table.. for a strange reason they weren't compatible.. 
so I created a sql code that would get yesterday's date and insert it without having to use a python date variable :)
I simply used:

> DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 day)

Here's my code 100% bullet proof:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from StringIO import StringIO
import numpy as np
import csv
import MySQLdb
import os


dict= {}
infile= open('csv_err1.log','r')
lines= infile.readlines()
for i in lines:
    eventKey, count, totalDuration, average   = [a.strip() for a in i.split(',')]
    dict.setdefault(eventKey, []).append((int(count), int(totalDuration), float(average)))



app_launch_time =dict["app_launch_time"][0][0]
bup_login_error =dict["bup_login_error"][0][0]
crash =dict["crash"][0][0]
parental_controls_error =dict["parental_controls_error"][0][0]
playback_error =dict["playback_error"][0][0]
qp_library_failed_reauthentication =dict["qp_library_failed_reauthentication"][0][0]
qp_library_failed_to_start =dict["qp_library_failed_to_start"][0][0]
search_error =dict["search_error"][0][0]
video_load_time =dict["video_load_time"][0][0]
tbr_error =dict["tbr_error"][0][0]
live_channels_metadata_request_failed =dict["live_channels_metadata_request_failed"][0][0]
vod_catalog_metadata_request_failed =dict["vod_catalog_metadata_request_failed"][0][0]

app_launch_time_avg =dict["app_launch_time"][0][2]
video_load_time_avg =dict["video_load_time"][0][2]


print ("app_launch_time", app_launch_time)
print ("bup_login_error",bup_login_error)
print ("crash ", crash )
print ("parental_controls_error", parental_controls_error)
print ("playback_error", playback_error)
print ("qp_library_failed_reauthentication", qp_library_failed_reauthentication)
print ("qp_library_failed_to_start", qp_library_failed_to_start)
print ("search_error", search_error)
print ("Video_load", video_load_time)
print ("tbr_error", tbr_error)
print ("live_channels_metadata_request_failed", live_channels_metadata_request_failed)
print ("vod_catalog_metadata_request_failed", vod_catalog_metadata_request_failed)
print ("app_launch_time_avg", app_launch_time_avg)
print ("Video_load", video_load_time_avg)


# Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="bravoecholimalima",db="capacityreports_mobiletv")

cursor = db.cursor()

# Prepare SQL query to INSERT a record into the database.
sql = ("""INSERT INTO errorscounted (date,app_launch_time,bup_login_error,crash, parental_controls_error,playback_error,qp_library_failed_reauthentication,qp_library_failed_to_start,search_error,video_load_time,tbr_error,live_channels_metadata_request_failed,vod_catalog_metadata_request_failed,app_launch_time_avg,video_load_time_avg) VALUES(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 day),%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""" %(app_launch_time,bup_login_error,crash,parental_controls_error,playback_error,qp_library_failed_reauthentication,qp_library_failed_to_start,search_error,video_load_time,tbr_error,live_channels_metadata_request_failed,vod_catalog_metadata_request_failed,app_launch_time_avg,video_load_time_avg))


try:
   # Execute the SQL command
   cursor.execute(sql)
   # Commit your changes in the database
   db.commit()
   for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print row[0]

except:
   # Rollback in case there is any error
   db.rollback()

# disconnect from server
cursor.close()
db.close()
```